# Datalist.DataSource issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have 1 `DataList`, and 2 `SqlDataSource`

I have initially set DataList1 to be paired with `SqlDataSource1`

and I have a button to change the `DataSource` to `SqlDataSource2`

```
DataList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

But by doing this, it throws me an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Both DataSource and DataSourceID
>   are defined on 'DataList1'.  Remove one definition.'

Any ideas? Is there a way to reset the datasource?

My html

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' Width="300px" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [items]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [items] WHERE ([Name] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Please share your grid HTML

Comment: Sure. I've edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error, you need to defined `DataSource` or `DataSourceID` to `DataList`, not both at the same time as in `DataList` HTML `DataSourceID` is defined and you need to clear it once you will define another data `DataSource`.

```
DataList1.DataSourceID = null;
DataList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Or remove `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"` from `DataList` HTML and define you `DataSource` in page load then you can set `DataList1.DataSource` to need `DataSource` directly.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```